# Database links not refreshing properly when a change the windows folder name

Tags: ms-access, path, vba

I have an Access 2013 database separated into two files - data and code.  In the code file, I have an autoexec routine to run the following function:

```
Function Reconnect()

    On Error GoTo ReconnectErr
    Dim db As Database, source As String, path As String
    Dim dbsource As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)

    For i = Len(db.Name) To 1 Step -1

        If Mid(db.Name, i, 1) = Chr(92) Then
            path = Mid(db.Name, 1, i)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    For i = 0 To db.TableDefs.Count - 1

        If db.TableDefs(i).Connect <> " " Then
            source = Mid(db.TableDefs(i).Connect, 11)

            For j = Len(source) To 1 Step -1

                If Mid(source, j, 1) = Chr(92) Then
                   dbsource = Mid(source, j + 1, Len(source))
                   source = Mid(source, 1, j)

                    If source <> path Then
                        db.TableDefs(i).Connect = ";Database=" + path + dbsource
                        db.TableDefs(i).RefreshLink
                    End If

                    Debug.Print dbsource, source
                    Exit For
                End If

             Next

        End If

    Next

    GoTo ReconnectEnd

ReconnectErr:

    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
ReconnectEnd:

End Function
```

The code works fine until I change the folder name (for instance, from MTDB to MTDB2)  When I launch, I get the following error:

"C:\Users...\OLDPATH\MT-Data.accdb is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."

Upon clicking OK, that same error occurs for each table object in the database.  When the program loads, I get empty recordsets.  I quit and relaunch and it works fine.

I suspect that there is a link reference somewhere before autoexec is called that carries the old path information and isn't updated at load time.

The code and data files will always be in the same folder.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error message when I change the name of the folder?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - if you have directed Access to open the startup form using Options/Current Database/Display Form, it apparently gets processed first in the hierarchy.  If you leave the Display Form blank and open it from the autoexec macro, it gets processed after the Reconnect() function gets called.